# Kendo mobile samples not workign with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms, kendo-ui

I am trying to develop kendo mobile apps using c# asp.net.
The sample html code works fine but when I put same code on .aspx page with form tag it doesn't render body.
Guys, do you know why that happens..Appreciate for your any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

An element with data-role="view" or data-role="layout" must be the first child of the body tag for Kendo Mobile. Try the following:

```
<body>
    <form runat="server" id="home" data-role="view" data-title="Home View">
        <div data-role="header"></div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <h1>Kendo Mobile ASP.net Web Forms</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Or pass the form as the element to initialize the Kendo Mobile application on:

<form id="mobileContainer" runat="server">
    <div data-role="view">
        kendo mobile view
    </div>
    <script>
        //set the form element as mobile application container
        new kendo.mobile.Application($("#mobileContainer"));
    </script>
</form>

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/application#using-kendo-ui-mobile-in-asp.net-webforms-project